# Can Widgets add custom stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, css, widget

I would like to insert a custom stylesheet from my custom-made Widget. Is that possible?

More specifically, I'm trying to use `jquery.fancybox` on a specific page and it needs `jquery.fancybox.css` for a correct visualization. I would prefer to exclude this file from ALL pages and insert it when the widget is actually used.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, unless you add `<style>` tags in your widget template.
I think this because the widgets are added to the content like this `{{widget ...}}`.
When these directives are parsed, the head tag is already rendered and you cannot add anything else to it.